# Meaning and usage of ain't

Tags: word-usage, meaning, register

Sometimes I encounter *ain't*, but I really don't know how to translate it properly.

What does *ain't* stand for? If I really wanted to use it, in which contexts would you say it's acceptable using it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Ain’t* is a negative present-tense form of the verbs *be* and *have* employed in all persons and numbers:

```
I ain't           we ain't
you ain't         you ain't
he/she/it ain't   they ain't
```

It represents a coalescence of the ordinary spoken contractions of *not* and the three relevant forms of the two verbs:

```
am not    ⊲   a’n’t  )  
are not   ⊲   a’n’t  )  
is not    ⊲   i’n’t  )  ⊲ e’n’t/ha’n’t ⊲ orthographic ain’t/hain't 
have not  ⊲  ha’n’t  )  
has not   ⊲  ha’n’t  )
```

It is used wherever *be not* is used: as a copula, in progressive constructions, and in passives; and where *have not* is used as an auxiliary, in perfect constructions.

*Ain’t* is not *slang* (which means, roughly, a fairly novel usage employed by an ‘in-group’ as a token of their ‘in-ness’) but a colloquialism which was at one time used virtually universally. You find it very often in 18th- and 19th-century plays and novels, in the mouths of persons of high social standing.

However, it aroused particular hostility among 19th century schoolmarms, who assaulted it ruthlessly and succeeded in painting it as **the** mark of illiterate speech. Accordingly, it **should not be used in formal contexts** except as an ironic nod to the vernacular. It is still very common in speech, but regarded as sub-standard rather than merely non-standard.

Comment: Or, *[don't, doesn't, didn't](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/meaning-of-aint-in-we-aint-know-what-it-meant)* (with a citation in support, @Kris).

Comment: @AlanCarmack Hmm ... that's interesting. I wonder though whether it **represents** *don't, doesn't, didn't* (perhaps via elision of /d/, which is quite common in my own dialect) or **replaces** them?

Answer (score 4):

> Ain't is used as a regular negated form of be or have, and supposedly
> sometimes do:
>
> - I ain't no tractor. = I am not a tractor.
> - I ain't got no tractor. = I haven't got any tractor.
>
> It's also used like there isn't, by common omission of there from
> there ain't.
>
> - Ain't no tractor here. = There isn't any tractor here.
>
> And in case you hadn't guessed, dialects that use ain't
> stereotypically use negative concord as well.

—Jon Purdy ([link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/usage-of-aint))

Answer (score 1):

The definition from the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ain%27t) says it all.

To summarise:

> Ain't:
>
> 1. Contraction of am not.
> 2. Used also as a contraction for are not, is not, has not, and have not.
>
> ...
>
> It may be that these extended uses helped fuel the negative reaction. Whatever the case, criticism of ain't by usage commentators
> and teachers has not subsided, and the use of ain't is often regarded
> as a sign of ignorance. · But despite all the attempts to ban it,
> ain't continues to enjoy extensive use in speech. Even educated and
> upper-class speakers see no substitute in folksy expressions such as
> *Say it ain't so* and *You ain't seen nothin' yet*.

So, basically, it's slang, but there are times when no other word fits.  I wouldn't use it in a formal situation, except to quote a title.  I'd use it sparingly except in very informal situations.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion "ain't" is just one more example of the incredible richness of the English language. When used in a formal context, or among speakers who don't normally use the word, it connotes a sense of "bringing the conversation back to earth" or steering an abstract, theoretical, or impractical discussion in a more practical direction.

For example, if a speaker believes he is being asked to discuss a very unlikely or inconsequential possibility, he may answer, "There are a whole lot of things I need to worry about, but that ain't one of them".