# Meaning of "ain't" in: "...we ain't know what it meant"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

What is the meaning of the following line:

> We ain't know what it meant

Putting `ain't = aren't` doesn't make sense. I'm left with putting `ain't = haven't`, but *have* requires the third form of *know*, which is *known*, and is not the case. If I put `ain't = don't` then it makes sense,

> We don't know what it meant

But the dictionary doesn't say that `ain't = don't`. So please explain me the meaning of that line.

Thank you.

Comment: Form where did you quote the sentence? I have a hunch it's simply not-really-thought-about grammar.

Comment: @MARamezani Type Ctrl+F and the sentense here, http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/yellowbrickroad.html

Comment: So it's the lyric of a song! My assumption of my hunch strengthens. But I'm not 100 percent sure, so I leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of the following line:
>
> > We ain't know what it meant

If you do a google search for '**we ain't know**' you get quite a lot of returns for the phrase in a context in which **didn't** fits nicely.

These include:

1

> We was young, we was dumb, we ain't know what was doing. But now that we older, older. Lets take these things slower, slower. Reset the button, button

2

> And we ain't know just what he had in store. But now here we are ten years later, flows got greater. Bonds got closer, plus it's more haters

A lot of these uses of 'We ain't know' are in other rap songs. Rap has its own vocabulary.

In addition Wikipedia [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Negation):

> some speakers of AAVE [African American Vernacular English] also use *ain't* instead of *don't*, *doesn't*, or *didn't* (e.g., *I ain't know that*).

Thus:
3

> We ain't know it 'til General Wheeler come thru and tell us. After that, de massa and missus let all de slaves go 'cepting me; they kept me to work in de house and ...

That seems to clear the matter up, since *didn't* fits the context of the rap song "[Yellow Brick Road](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/eminem/yellowbrickroad.html)" by ([Eminem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem)).

Here is the opening part of Verse 3 of the song:

> My first year in 9th grade, can't forget that day at school
> It was cool till your man MC Shan came through
> And said that Puma's The Brand 'cause the clan makes troops
> It was rumors but man, god damn, they flew
> Must've been true because man we done banned they shoes
> I had the new ones the Cool J, Ice land swayed too
> And we just through them in the trash like they yesterday's news
> Guess who came through next, X-clan debut
> Professor X vanglorious exists in a state of red, black, and green
> With a key sissies now with this being a new trend
> We don't fit in crackers is out with Cactus albums
> Blackness is in, African symbols and medallions
> Represents black power and **we ain't know what it meant**
> Me and my man Howard and Butter, we would go to the mall with 'em
> All over our necks like we're showing 'em off not knowing at all
> We was being laughed at you ain't even half black
> You ain't supposed to have that homie let me grab that
> And that Flavor Flave clock we gonna have to snatch that

Again, *ain't* fits perfectly as **didn't**.

The song is an auto-biographical narrative in which Eminem hearkens back to his first day(s) in 9th grade (a grade he failed twice before dropping out of high school) and remembering various events and moments. Not surprisingly an important topic is brands of athletic shoes, including Puma.

Eminem is a [cracker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cracker), semi-offensive slang for a poor white boy. He attends a school with lots of black students. They make fun of Eminem when he and his friends wear African symbols and medallions. In the middle of this Eminem says **we ain't know what it meant.**

*Ain't* occurs 5 times in the song. All five instances are in Verse 3.

For those interested, here is [youtube version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Emk1mnNqEE) that has the lyrics scroll as they are recited. There are a few mild-ish swear words. Stanza 3 begins right after the repeated chorus at 2:57.

---

Last, while I was pondering this question, I wrote the following section. It does not seem as relevant now, but I'm including it so that it wasn't a wasted effort. It also shows that you cannot always trust dictionaries. But then again, I've never been impressed with the ODO.

*Ain't* [usually signifies](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ain%27t)

1. a negative form of *to be*
2. the negative form *have not* / *has not*

(Note: One of the ODO's examples for *has /  have not* actually means *aren't*.  This is the first example under 1.1 "More Example Sentences".  In this example '[Baseball's origins ain't found till they're found](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/09/12/sports/baseball/12origins.html?_r=0)', *ain't* means *aren't*. Not only is this clear from the clause itself; but the title is an allusion to the [famous axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra#Quotations) of former New York Yankee catcher Yogi Berra: 'It ain't over till it's over.' In which *ain't* also signifies the verb *to be*. In English, axioms are stated in the present tense.)

Comment: How is the first example of meaning 2 is actually an example of meaning 1? The example is, `they ain’t got nothing to say` Here `ain't != am not/are not`, here `ain't=haven't`, `they haven't got nothing to say`.

Comment: @user31782 I meant the first example under "More Example Sentences". I'll edit my post.

Comment: What does _ain't_ mean in _if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it_?

Comment: If it isn't broke(n), don't fix it.

Comment: I have asked it separately [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46858/3448). Could you explain in detail there.

Answer (score 2):

STRAY CATS

"Little Miss Prissy"
http://www.oldielyrics.com/lyrics/stray_cats/little_miss_prissy.html

> Well I know a little lady, she lives down London way,
>
> She talks and talks all night, but she ain't got much to say.

Here's another use of "ain't" as *don't/doesn't*. Ain't is mainly used as *am/is/are not* but can basically be used as a general negative helper verb. My father's family comes from a town that still doesn't have a traffic light, and I spend part of every vacation back home helping with the cattle and the hogs, so I hear "ain't" plenty.

(Sorry, having a horrific time editing this post for some reason.)

Comment: Is `She ain't got = She hasn't got` or `She ain't got = She don't got`?

Comment: I'd prefer "She doesn't have" but of what you've listed, "She hasn't got." Since 'got' is the main verb, *ain't* replaces the negative copula *hasn't*.

Comment: Where does in the song, that you have quoted, they use `ain't` as `don't/doesn't`?

Comment: OH, I SEE! Sorry! "She don't/doesn't got" is still bad grammar, but yes, that's how I was reading it. I should have made that more clear. It matches with your example. It could also be "She hasn't" if the sentence were different. When I replied to your comment a few minutes ago, I had been in the sci-fi stack exchange and was a bit slow to reconnect to ELL.

Comment: So, `she ain't got` means `she don't got`? By the way are you native English speaker?

Answer (score 1):

"ain't", substandard, can be used for: am/are/is not and have/has not. Sometimes it is even used for do/does not. It seems some people use it as a general marker for negation, even in Past tense. Seems like Afrikaans which has astonishing simplifications.

Comment: So what does ain't mean in the  sentence the OP asks about? Because to me, so far it seems your answer is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @CarSmack - You've already said it in your post.

Answer (score -1):

It's terrible (incorrect) English.  But here *ain't* means *didn't*.

EDIT: or *don't*, if we're looking back on the past and still not knowing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _don't_ instead of _didn't_? The sentence is "We ain't know what it **meant** (the second form)."

Comment: It could be either *don't* or *didn't*, depending on *when* we don't/didn't know.

Comment: [I have been told that Eminem is a talented professional and my personal belief is that his songs are not likely to contain **incorrect** English](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26391/3448). I believe that whatever native English speakers speak for communicating is **correct** English. Eminem must have used vernacular English in that line.

Comment: Eminem intentionally uses non-standard English in his songs.  The reasons for this are artistic and cultural, in order to suggest a low socio-economic status.  Therefore I would not suggest using such English in a job interview, and I wouldn't encouraging those learning English as a second language to emulate it.

Comment: My point is that it's not incorrect English. Rather it is the correct use of a dialect. Why shouldn't I use it in a job interview? Do they consider socio-economic background rather the technical skills?

Comment: They look for indicators of education and high intelligence.  This is the opposite of that.

Comment: Socio-economic Background has nothing to do with intelligence.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward.  If you speak like this, people will assume you're uneducated, because educated people learn *not* to speak like this.  I have interviewed many people for jobs.  If they are native English speakers and talk like this, I will question their competence.  If they are not native English speakers, I wouldn't judge them for speaking like this.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read [CoolHandLouis's](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26391/3448) answer--especially this part, _...Some would support the notion that people are not "educated vs. not-educated". They are educated to various degrees along various dimensions. Stan certainly has a penchant for communicating his ideas clearly and succinctly. And that seems more educated than many high school (dare I say even college) graduates._

Comment: I did read the answer.  As an interviewer, I don't have time to get to know you personally.  I am going to judge you by what comes out of your mouth.  If it sounds dumb (by not being Standard English, which is expected in a job interview), then I will think that you are dumb.  That's just reality.

Comment: If they are fully competent, but still speak AAVE, would you hire them?

Comment: How do you define standard English? CoolHandLouis said that  There is no single official standard for correct English grammar. I, for one, would wary from giving interview in a company which considers a dialect dumb.

Comment: Educated African Americans speak both Standard English *and* AAVE. Just like educated folk from the South speak both Southern American and Standard English. The uneducated of both groups speak whatever they speak.

Comment: Can you provide evidence that *ain't* means *didn't* here? How do you know it doesn't mean *hadn't*?

Comment: I think if it meant *hadn't*, then it would be "ain't known" instead of "ain't know"

Comment: But answers are supposed to be supported with evidence. Not *I think*. Perhaps especially when discussing dialects that are not our own.

Comment: As an educated speaker of AmE for 40 years, I'm not sure what more evidence you require.  Perhaps you should provide evidence to the contrary.