# "I ain't got no" vs "i don't have any"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I was using this messenger app Waike and i found one of user posting **I ain't got no money**. I felt it should be **I don't have any money**.

So does this both have same meaning or what?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered. Excellent answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/410/meaning-and-usage-of-aint).

Comment: Laure: the question is not only about "ain't", there is a double negative to consider too.

Comment: @Laure I know what ain't means. but I am wondering how it can be used in negative manner as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: [Ain't and negatives](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/aint-and-negatives) and [“You ain't no Human.”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75048/you-aint-no-human-what-is-the-need-of-no-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ain't got no money

is technically incorrect, but conforms to a widely used idiom; native English speakers would recognise the meaning.

First, **ain't** is a very informal (scorned by strict schoolteachers) contraction of **am not**. As the question referenced by Laure indicates there are similar contractions for **have not**, but I have rarely heard those used.

So a more usual use of **ain't**

> I ain't goin' to school today

would mean

> I am not going to school today.

We need to read ain't as meaning **have not** in the question's example; this would be understood by native speakers.

The second issue here is that there is a double negative

> I have not got no money

so a pedant will say:  "if you do not have **no money** you must have **some money**"

So, yes, would be more correct to say

> I do not have any money

or

> I have no money

However there is no actual ambiguity here we all understand

> I ain't no money

and similarly

> I ain't go nobody to love me ...

These formulations are common in traditional Blues songs.

Comment: So basically It's not correct but still used widely?

Comment: Widely understood. Rarely said by well-educated people; I would only say it in a joking way where I was confident that my listeners know that **I** know it's not correct English.